# JSON parsing error. Key not found even though it exists

Tags: java, json, parsing, pubnub

This is my code snippet. I am trying to send a JSON message from PUBNUB to my system and parse it. My key is **"CMD"**. 
This is what I am sending from pubnub `{"CMD":"hey"}`

```
public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {


   Object PlainTextMessage = new AESDecrypt().Decrypt(message);
   JSONObject jsonMsg = new JSONObject(PlainTextMessage);
   try {
      String command = jsonMsg.getString("CMD");
      System.out.println(command);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the error I get

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["CMD"] not found.  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:405)  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:586)    at
>   PubNub.Subscribe$1.successCallback(Subscribe.java:45)     at
>   com.pubnub.api.Callback.successWrapperCallback(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore.invokeSubscribeCallback(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore.access$1100(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore$14.handleResponse(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.pubnub.api.SubscribeWorker.process(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.pubnub.api.Worker.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I tried escaping the double quotes, but doesnt work.
Can anyone give me an idea of what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are decrypting it correctly?

Comment: The decryption for now is just a dummy function which simply returns the input value.

Comment: your code should be correct based on the info you provided, but I think something else must be wrong, try logging `jsonMsg.toString()`

Comment: @meda This is weird. `jsonMsg.toString()` outputs a pair of empty braces `{}`. By the way I have now removed the decrypt function. Now the `message` object goes directly into the `jsonMsg` object

Comment: @searcotjabali log `message`, if you get `{"CMD":"hey"}` it means the code should work. You can also make sure you convert to a String `new JSONObject((String)PlainTextMessage);`

Comment: @meda I output`message` and I get `{"CMD":"hey"}`. Casting PlainTextMessage to a string gives me org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: ok so use `.toString()` on `message` or it means `message` is already the JSON object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94719/discussion-between-searcot-jabali-and-meda).

Comment: Hey it worked!!
Thanks @meda.
Could give me an idea of why it was necessary to cast it? I thought JSON would work with multi type data in a single object

Comment: @searcotjabali see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation for `.org.json`

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)

The constructor of JSONObject , takes a String not an Object, so the cast is necessary

**JSONObject**

```
public JSONObject(java.lang.String source)
           throws JSONException
```

> Construct a JSONObject from a source JSON text string. This is the
>   most commonly used JSONObject constructor.

**Parameters:**

> source - A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with }
>   (right brace). Throws:
>
> JSONException - If there is a syntax error in the source string or a
>   duplicated key.